# How to show if $M$ is convex set then $\ker(M)$ is convex?

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $L$ be real linear space and $M\subset L$ is convex. Show that
>   $\ker(M)$ is convex

$\ker(M):=\{x:x\in M$ for all $y\in L$ there is $\epsilon = \epsilon(x,y)>0$, for every  $|t|<\epsilon$, $x+ty\in M\}$

let $x_1,x_2\in \ker(M)$ and $\alpha\in [0,1]$. for any $y\in L$, there is $\epsilon_1=\epsilon_1(x_1,y)>0$ st for $|t|<\epsilon_1$, $x_1+ty\in M$ and there is $\epsilon_2=\epsilon_2(x_2,y)>0$ st for $|t|<\epsilon_2$, $x_2+ty\in M$

when we choose $\epsilon=\min \{\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2\}$ . for $|t|<\epsilon$, $x_1+ty\in M$ and $x_2+ty\in M$.

edit : for $\lambda \in [0,1]$

$$
\begin{align}
& (\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2) + ty \\[6pt]
= {} &\lambda x_1+\lambda ty+(1-\lambda )x_2 + (1-\lambda )ty \\[6pt]
= {} & \lambda (x_1+ty)+(1- \lambda)(x_2+ty)\in M
\end{align}
$$

because $x_1+ty$ and $x_2+ty\in M$ and  M is convex.  so $ (\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2) + ty \in M$ .again $(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2)\in M$ because $M$ is convex. so $(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2)\in \ker(M)$. it means $\ker(M)$ is convex.

Comment: You're almost there. "So for $\lambda \in [0,1]$ and $\lvert t\rvert < \epsilon$, we have $(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2) + ty\dotsc$"

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks!. Is this correct now?

Comment: Yup, it's fine.